# Kafka Connect Elasticsearch Sink Connector Metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to get the following information from the Mbeans exposed by Confluent's Kafka Connect Sink Connector for Elasticsearch?

- Lag / Offset Delay
- Events sink rate 1m / 5m / 15m
- Events sink latency
- Skipped events
- Total number of events seen, skipped, filtered.

I could only find the sink task and the batch size metrics (attached). I couldn't find any section dedicated to metrics in the [official docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/configuration_options.html). Debezium, for example, has a [full fledged page](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/operations/monitoring.html) dedicated to monitoring

[image: Metrics]

Comment: How are you defining `essential`?

Comment: It's described at the end of the problem statement, in a bulleted list.

Comment: Your link is to the Elastic connector configuration, there is a separate page in the docs for JMX metrics that Kafka Connect itself exposes

Comment: Those are the Kafka Connect metrics that I've already mentioned. Where are the "Elasticsearch Sink" specific metrics?